# C++ calculations not printing in proper format

Tags: c++, arrays, calculation

I am working on a homework assignment and when I run my program my calculations are being displayed as -7.40477e+61. I am using visual studio as my IDE and when I check my code on an online checker it displays just fine. I am not sure why everything is being printed in that format. Any advice would be great!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    double dArr[5];
    long lArr[7] = { 100000, 134567, 123456, 9, -234567, -1, 123489 };
    int iArr[3][5];
    char sName[30] = "fjksdfjls fjklsfjs";
    short cnt1, cnt2;
    long double total = 0;
    double average;
    long highest;

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    for (int val : dArr) {
        dArr[val] = rand() % 100000 + 1;
        cout << dArr[val] << endl;
    }

    for (int count = 0; count < 5; count++) {
        total += dArr[count];
        average = total / 5;
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "The total of the dArr array is " << total << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "The average of the dArr array is " << average << endl;
    cout << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what `cout << dArr[val] << endl;` this is printing? Is this also e+61?

Comment: Yes that line of code prints the 5 random numbers. Its the for loop after that which is the one for the total and the average that is giving me the e+61

Comment: I think you need to reexamine this: `for (int val : dArr) {` Hint: `val` is not an index.

Comment: @drescherjm  Yep. both  `for (int val : dArr)` and `dArr[val] = ...` are incorrect.

Comment: ***when I check my code on an online checker it displays just fine*** Sometimes by random bad luck Undefined Behavior produces a result that looks correct. My guess is the online source gave you memory that was initialized to 0.

Comment: `for (int count = 0; count < 5; count++) {` looks like a better choice for a for loop with an index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The range-based `for` loop:

```
for (int val : dArr)
```

iterates `val` over the *values* of the collection `dArr`, *not* the indexes of that collection. So, when you attempt:

```
dArr[val] = rand() % 100000 + 1;
```

within said loop, it's unlikely to to give you the results you expect. Since `dArr` is local to `main`, it may have *any* values in it.

A better way would be to mirror your second loop, with something like:

```
for (int count = 0; count < 5; count++) {
    dArr[val] = rand() % 100000 + 1;
    cout << dArr[val] << endl;
}
```

---

Having said that, there appears to be no *real* reason why you're storing these numbers in an array at all (unless there's something about that in the problem statement that isn't shared in this question).

All you really *need* to do is keep the total, and the count so you can work out the mean. That could be as simple as (I've also changed the code to use Herb Sutter's AAA style, "almost always auto"):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    const auto count = 5U;

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    auto total = 0.0L;
    for (auto index = 0U; index < count; ++index) {
        const auto value = rand() % 100000 + 1;
        cout << value << "\n";
        total += value;
    }

    const auto average = total / count;
    cout << "\nThe total of the dArr array is " << total << "\n";
    cout << "The average of the dArr array is " << average << "\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you, I think it was the random numbers that was throwing me off